# Recharts - limit the number of ticks on x-axis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I have a button to switch between charts, but sometimes the x-axis data contains 300 ticks, whereas sometimes it contains 90 ticks.

My x-axis looks like so:
`<XAxis dataKey="time" interval={10}  />`

This looks great for data with 90 ticks, however when it comes to 300 ticks all of the labels are mashed together because there are so many.

How can I normalize this so that there are always 11 evenly spread out labels on the x-axis no matter the number of data points?

Comment: You could try `minTickGap={15}` - [see docs](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis#minTickGap)

Answer (score -1):

I had to limit the number of data points on the X-Axis as well today and thought I'd share my approach (even though your question was asked over a year ago).

All you have to do is to set the interval attribute using a simple calculation:

```
 <XAxis dataKey="Name" interval={xAxisInterval} />

// To determine the interval for the desired number of X-Axis
// data points (e.g. 11) use the formula below
let xAxisInterval = Math.round(sampleData.length / xAxisDataPoints);
```

Sandbox environment and example code below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-recharts-limit-the-number-of-ticks-on-x-axis-x9c5vm

```
import React from "react";
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend } from "recharts";

export default function App() {
  let arrayLength = 90; // Change this value to 90 or 300...
  let xAxisDataPoints = 11; // Desired number of labels on X-Axis

  // Create some sample data below...
  let sampleData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    sampleData.push({
      Name: i,
      Amount: Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000
    });
  }

  // Determine interval to display the desired number of X-Axis data points
  let xAxisInterval = Math.round(sampleData.length / xAxisDataPoints);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LineChart width={750} height={250} data={sampleData}>
        <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
        <XAxis dataKey="Name" interval={xAxisInterval} />
        <YAxis type="number" />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Amount" stroke="#0095FF" />
      </LineChart>
    </div>
  );
}
```